# How to connect to a bridged Docker network from the host?

Tags: windows, docker

**Context**

I have a docker bridged network, and two linux containers connected and running.
The two linux machines can ping successfully each other using the network ip respectively 172.19.0.2 and 172.19.0.3

I am using Docker v20.10.17 on Windows, (with WSL2 integration, hopefully this does not matter)

**Question**

I executed the ipconfig /all, and see no (virtual) adapters on this subnet...
How can I connect my host to this network?

Comment: Docker is probably (I am not familiar with any recent changes around WSL) running inside a Linux virtual machine. The docker bridge interface exists inside that virtual machine, not on the host. To see the bridge interface you would need to log into the linux vm and run e.g., `ip addr show`.

Comment: That's why I figured out the 172.19.0.2 and 172.19.0.3 I wrote in OP...

Comment: Having the exact same issue, if you ended up solving it I'd love it if you shared how.

Answer (score 0):

With WSL2 it is kind of crazy what you have to do.

Make sure your WSL2 instance is running.

Windows: start->run - type ncpa.cpl

Pick your WSL vEthernet adapter and your physical ethernet adapter and bridge them.

Note you will lose internet on your windows machine unless you do some other stuff but this should get you to a starting point.

[image: bridgeconnection]